# GoogleApiClient connection failed with ConnectionResult statuscode SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

[EDIT] - For Bounty

I am trying to connect my android application with Google Drive to sync, MP3 audio files. Need working code/examples (apart from the links given below) for connecting with Google Drive using the GoogleDriveAndroidApi and GoogleApiClient.

---

This question has been asked many number of times, but none of them had a solution for the question. So, i am asking this again.

I am working on Google Drive Android API for the first time, and couldn't pass through the "Choose account for 'APP NAME'" screen. Here is what i doing as of now:

1. Tried to follow the urls below:

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/

2. Using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1' in my build.gradle (if that makes any difference)
3. Code tried so far:

   ```
    public class ARCBackupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
               GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

           private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

           private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
           private Toolbar mToolbar;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.arc_activity_backup);

               mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
               setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

               getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
               getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
               getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

           }


           @Override
           protected void onResume() {
               super.onResume();
               if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                   // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
                   // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
                   // failures.
                   // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
                   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                           .addApi(Drive.API)
                           .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                           .build();
               }
               // Connect the client. 
               mGoogleApiClient.connect();
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPause() {
               if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                   mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
               }
               super.onPause();
           }

           @Override
           protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
               switch (requestCode) {

                   case REQUEST_CODE:

                       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                       }
                       break;
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
               // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
               Log.i(Const.DEBUG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
               if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                   // show the localized error dialog.
                   GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
                   return;
               }
               // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
               // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
               // authorization
               // dialog is displayed to the user.
               try {
                   result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE);
               } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                   Log.e(Const.DEBUG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
               Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "API client connected.");

               //saveFileToDrive();
           }

           @Override
           public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
               Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
           }
       }
   ```

   What is that i am missing here? Any complete example with good explanation is much appreciated.

   Let me know if i need to give more info to solve the issue

   [EDIT 1]

   If i add `Plus.API` while building the googleApiClient, it solves the problem of getting stuck in the loop of choosing the account. But, Plus.API is deprecated, is there a workaround for this just by using GoogleApiClient?

   Here is the changed code:

   ```
    @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();

           if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
               Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
               mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
           }


           if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
               // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
               // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
               // failures.
               // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
               mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                       .addApi(Drive.API)
                       .addApi(Plus.API)
                       .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                       .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                       .build();
           }
           // Connect the client.
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
       }
   ```

Still looking for the correct way of implementing...

Comment: "Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose" -  does that happen? If you get that screen, then it works. Your error is that you need to login to a valid account

Comment: @cricket_007, yes i get the choose account screen. Once i select the account, the same screen is shown again and again as a loop.

Comment: @cricket_007, can you check my edited code and let me know what is the best way to implement GoogleApiClient correctly?

Comment: I've never done it myself, but if the plus api is deprecated, I'd read the documentation about what the alternative is

Comment: Try this :go to the google api console from your gmail account. Here you will see a disable button in front of Google drive api. just right to that you will see a gear or setting button click on it and generate oAuth token.

Comment: @VamsiChalla do this thing let me if your issue sort out or not?? or is their any other issue comes up??

Comment: @VamsiChalla : In onactivityResult  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)  { Then do you can check if you are getting list of files}

Comment: @VamsiChalla : If (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {                       mGoogleApiClient.connect(); } : this might be issue. Once u got the result ok, the u can proceed with your stuff.

Comment: You can refer to this answer, if you have not specified the Signing Keystore in Android studio:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/42441460/673910

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that the problem you have is because of

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Let me explain. When the account chooser appears it makes your activity to call onPause(). And in onPause() you calls *mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()*.

As result, you have new GoogleApiClient after account selection (when onResume and onActivityResult is called).

To fix the problem just place *mGoogleApiClient.connect()* and *mGoogleApiClient.disconnect()* to onStart()/onStop() methods of your activity or use *enableAutoManage(Activity, OnConnectionFailedListener)* for you GoogleApiClient.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: moving the code to onStart() and onStop() solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was going through issues for Google drive on github ,i found the similar issue their go through @iuribtt answer

Here is link

[Google Drive Issues](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/43)

In case this link got expired I am posting his answer :

Try to use "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\XXXXX.android\debug.keystore -list -v"
and not the keystore that you generate, once you want the debug mode.

The path for the "debug.keystore" and the password is "android"
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#android

And after that create the project in https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Finally, enable the Drive API in the https://console.developers.google.com

Hope this Helps!!!Cheers!!!

Comment: I think you have to setup both production and debug keys in console.