# Google OAuth2 on Android - How to test it without Play Store?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api

I developed an app which uses for example the Google Calendar API. I used this guide to develop my app: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/android . I'm accessing the calendar list with google calendar api. This works fine, when I upload it to the signed APK to Google Play Store. But when I try it on my computer in Android Studio in simulator, then accessing the google calendar api causes the app to load and load and it does simply does nothing.

Now I want to develop a new app. I want to access Google Drive API. So I took this guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android . I've done everything in the guide descriped and copied all the source code one to one in my app. But what I get is nothing but an error in the console:

> The following error occurred:
>   null

Is there no possibility to use Google API until you upload a signed APK to the Play Store?

Comment: Your issue could be any of a hundred things but iot's pretty tough for anyone to help you without seeing any of your code, but there's got to be differences in between what you have and what they instructions say.  You need to go through each page again, step by step, and make sure that you're doing exactly what the instructions say, and nothing else.

Comment: I tried again with this instruction, but it doesnt work: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android

Comment: You can test Google APIs in Android without having to upload on Playstore. You're problems seems to arise from you piling codes together and expecting them to work. Can you try one quickstart at a time?

Comment: Helo, Now I've copied the example from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android one to one. The only difference is that I renamed the package name to de.ubik.quickstart . When I click the button in the example it gives: "The following error occured: null". Do i have to wait until the api is activated? Can I run the apis in Emulator?

Comment: Ok, now I've got it. Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105917/googleapiclient-connection-failed-with-statuscode-sign-in-required