# G+ connection failed statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-plus

Why I'm getting this error? I already created a project in Google Developer Console, enabled Drive API and Google+ API and added "Android Client Id" with my signed apk's sha1 (I already shared as beta on google play console by the way).
I get permissions **`GET_ACCOUNTS`** and when I choose my G+ mail in list, I'm getting this error:

```
 D/G+: Connection failed4ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent
```

Do I have to add **`client_id.json`** somewhere in my project folder? (I just created it in Google Developer Console for Drive API.)

codes:

```
      // initialize g+ api client
    if (Sp.getBoolean("plus_pic", false)) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();
    }
```

and:

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

        String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Person.Image personImage;
        Person.Cover.CoverPhoto personCover;

        try {

            personImage = currentPerson.getImage();
            personCover = currentPerson.getCover().getCoverPhoto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("G+ COnnection error"," ->"+e.toString());
            personCover = null;
            personImage = null;
        }

        if (personCover != null && personImage != null) {

            String imgUrl = personImage.getUrl();
            Log.e("g+ connection","cover and pic not null");
            // getting full size image
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(imgUrl);
            stringBuilder.delete(imgUrl.length() - 6, imgUrl.length());
            Log.d("G+", stringBuilder.toString());
            mGoogleName.setText(currentPerson.getDisplayName());
            mGoogleId.setText(accountName);
            // setting cover pic
            ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(personCover.getUrl(), displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    drawerHeaderParent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        drawerHeaderView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));
                    } else
                        drawerHeaderView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
                    drawerHeaderView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_header);
                    drawerHeaderParent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((currentTab == 1 ? skinTwo : skin)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                    drawerHeaderView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_header);
                    drawerHeaderParent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((currentTab == 1 ? skinTwo : skin)));
                }
            });

            // setting profile pic
            ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(stringBuilder.toString(), displayImageOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    drawerProfilePic.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                    drawerProfilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
                }
            });


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getText(R.string.no_cover_photo), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            drawerHeaderView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.app_header);
            drawerHeaderParent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor((currentTab == 1 ? skinTwo : skin)));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    Log.d("G+", "Connection suspended");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }).run();
}

public void onConnectionFailed(final ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.d("G+", "Connection failed"+ result.getErrorCode()+result.toString());

    if (!mIntentInProgress && result.hasResolution()) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mIntentInProgress = true;
                    startIntentSenderForResult(result.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                    // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).run();
    }
}
```

and:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && !mGoogleApiKey && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiKey = true;
                // !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                } else
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

            }
        }).run();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the error [`SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) because the client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in.

> The client may choose to continue without using the API. Alternately, if [`hasResolution()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#hasResolution()) returns true the client may call [`startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity, int)) to prompt the user to sign in. After the sign in activity returns with [`RESULT_OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK) further attempts should succeed.

Based from this [forum](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/49), try to resolve this issue by going to the Google API console from your gmail account. There you will see a disable button in front of Google Drive API. You will see a gear or setting button, click on it and generate oAuth token.

Here are some related threads:

- [GoogleApiClient connection failed with statusCode SIGN_IN_REQUIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105917/googleapiclient-connection-failed-with-statuscode-sign-in-required)
- [onConnectionFailed giving SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736137/onconnectionfailed-giving-sign-in-required4)
- [Google+ sign in error with statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770243/google-sign-in-error-with-statuscode-sign-in-required-on-android-4)

Hope this helps!

Comment: i already generated auth2 token and i imported google_services.json to "app/" folder and i'm getting this error.Do i have to use that client_id in my code?

Comment: btw i checked your links there is no answered question i think many ppl are faced with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my cause i wrongly used release SHA1 key to generate API in developer console. Then created SHA1 key with debug.keystore and updated in my api credentials. Its started working.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\<user>n\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass andro
id -keypass android
```